# page.waitForTimeout() in pyppeteer?

Tags: python, puppeteer, sleep, pyppeteer

I have a pyppeteer (not puppeteer) browser with many pages opened, and I'd like to wait for example 2 second before doing other stuff on some of these pages.
I tried to use time.sleep() but it looks like it blocks the execution of all pages.

Is there an equivalent to page.waitForTimeout() in pyppeteer ?
I think I could also use multithreading but I'd like not to.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind,

```
page.waitFor(2000)
```

does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `time.sleep` in asynchronous is `asyncio.sleep`. So use:

```
await asyncio.sleep(2)  # 2 second non-blocking sleep
```